# R Data points perimeter buffer

Tags: r, computational-geometry

I need to create a buffer zone on the set of [data points](http://www.dropbox.com/s/rd90azgjwhsk6ll/data.csv?dl=0) with x and y coordinates (grey points on the graph). 
Unfortunately, I don’t have a perimeter border of the points, from which to create a buffer. 
I was trying to calculate the perimeter using `chull` function, however it is not working properly (orange area). 
I can calculate the border points using `max`/`min` functions for the data by some step (let's say 10 m, red dots), and try to calculate the buffer from those points.
Is someone aware of more correct and clean way to calculate the buffer zone for set of points.

[image]

Comment: Is the red line the result that you are looking for?

Comment: I would like to retrieve all the points that fall inside the polygon identified by red line.

Comment: `chull` is working properly. You just don't want your hull to be "convex".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks a lot for your suggestions and comments.
Indeed, It was my fault omitting the `alphahull` package.

After identifying the border with `ashape` I create a buffer polygon and identified the data that lies inside and outside the buffer. Challenge was to correctly extract the polygon from `ashap`, but solution of [RPubs](http://rpubs.com/geospacedman/alphasimple) safe me.
You can see also the graphical example [here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9p3vv25xkwrpxur/Buffer.jpeg?dl=0)

Best

```
## load
library(ggplot2); library(alphahull); 
library(igraph); library(rgeos)
## Load the data
data.df<-read.csv("Data/Cencus/Lyford_meta.csv",sep=",",header=TRUE)

#Remove the duplicates in the data to do the chull calculation
data <- data.df[!duplicated(paste(data.df$xsite, data.df$ysite, sep ="_")), c("xsite","ysite") ]

#calculate the chull with alpha 20
data.chull <- ashape(data, alpha = 20)


## Below is the code to extract polygon from the ashape chull function 
## credit to: http://rpubs.com/geospacedman/alphasimple
order.chull <- graph.edgelist(cbind(as.character(data.chull$edges[, "ind1"]), as.character(data.chull$edges[,"ind2"])), directed = FALSE)
cutg <- order.chull - E(order.chull)[1]
ends <- names(which(degree(cutg) == 1))
path <- get.shortest.paths(cutg, ends[1], ends[2])[[1]]
pathX <- as.numeric(V(order.chull)[unlist(path[[1]])]$name)
pathX = c(pathX, pathX[1])
data.chull <- as.data.frame(data.chull$x[pathX, ])


## Create a spatial object from the polygon and apply a buffer to
## Then extract the data to the dataframe.
data.chull.poly <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(as.matrix(data.chull))),"s1")))
data.chull.poly.buff <- gBuffer(data.chull.poly, width = -10)
data.buffer <- fortify(data.chull.poly.buff)[c("long","lat")]

## Identidfy the data that are inside the buffer polygon
data$posit <- "Outside"
data$posit[point.in.polygon(data$x,data$y,data.buffer$long,data.buffer$lat) %in% c(1,2,3)] <- "Inside"


## Plot the results
ggplot()+
  theme_bw()+xlab("X coordinates (m)")+ylab("Y coordinates (m)") +
  geom_point(data = data, aes(xsite, ysite, color = posit))+
  geom_polygon(data = data.chull, aes(V1, V2), color = "black", alpha = 0)+
  geom_polygon(data = data.buffer, aes(long, lat), color = "blue", alpha = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do a tesselation around the points. Points at the border will have much larger polygons.

```
library(deldir)
library(ggplot2)
triang <- deldir(data$x, data$y)
border <- triang$summary
border$Selected <- border$dir.area > 260
ggplot(border[order(border$Selected), ], aes(x = x, y = y, colour = Selected)) + geom_point()
```